# Adding multiple StyleSheet to Single Element

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have element named `<td>`. 
My sample code

```
<td style="{style}"   tabIndex="0" {newStyle}/>
where {style} =style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;"
where {newStyle}=style=" text-decoration: line-through;"
```

My question here is will both stylesheets concatenate or first one`{style}` will be applied or second one `{newStyle}` will be applied.

Comment: But in IE , in my application {newStlye} is sometimes carry style property as i mentioned, but some cases it will carry non style property i.e subid:"255", i need if its style it should be appended,else it will be part of element property

Answer (score 1):

It's against the HTML5 spec to declare an attribute (including `style`) twice for the same element. Chances are some browsers will ignore the second declaration while others will accept it. But it looks, from a quick search, like most browsers will opt to ignore the second declaration.

Comment: In any case, it won't happen that a browser uses the values of both attributes. That would be a serious bug!